# How to enable trace and traceLimit with ngrx?

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular8, redux-devtools-extension

I am trying to enable trace and traceLimit (this feature https://extension.remotedev.io/docs/Features/Trace.html) on ngrx/store-devtools.

I am currently using these packages and version, and running Angular 8.

"@ngrx/store": "^8.0.1"

"@ngrx/store-devtools": "^8.0.1"

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({}, ),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
      maxAge: 25,
      logOnly: false,
      trace: true // KINDA EXPECTING AN OPTION LIKE THIS BUT SEEMS TO NOT BE SUPPORTED
    }),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, ],
}, )
```

I would like to see the stack in the Redux DevTools Chrome extension.

Comment: https://ngrx.io/guide/store-devtools/config#configuration-object-properties

Comment: @Jota.Toledo there is nothing about trace and tracelimit in that link

Comment: seems it's there only it's not in the type def
https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/pull/624

Comment: try like this and see if it works    `StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument(<any>{
      trace: true,
    })`

Comment: btw seems there is no trace in their source
https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/store-devtools/src/config.ts

Answer (score 5):

These features are only enabled in a redux application.

Because of this, the test view is also disabled. See https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/1868 for more info.

Comment: Thanks Tim for your work on Ngrx. It appears this feature has been implemented since you wrote this answer, so I've added another answer with the updated information.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that in 2022 the trace features were implemented in ngrx. Git issue: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/pull/3665.

Trace worked for me by configuring the devtool connection appropriately in my Angular module file. Where you would normally set up instrumentation, add the configuration for trace.

```
    !environment.production ? StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({ 
      trace: true
    }) : [],
```